# JobID before Send

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are building a journey with a condition to check whether a subscriber clicked on a specific link within an email.

The url of that link has dynamic tags `&jobid = %%jobid%%`. However, with this tag, the url doesn't show up in the list of urls to choose from in the journey condition.

when we remove the dynamic tag, then we can select it as a click condition.

We tested it with a hardcoded dummy jobid and it works fine then. So the question is - how do we find what the jobid is before we hit send? Or does jobid only get created when the email is sent.

Comment: Could you try adding an "alias" tag to the URL in your email - <a alias="banner" href="myurliwthparams...

Answer (score 2):

A JobID is created when the email is scheduled, and editing the email after it is scheduled will require you to reschedule the email (thus creating a new JobID).

Are you able to use Email Name or Link Name instead of JobID? There are personalization strings for %%emailname_%% and %%linkname%% - if this email is a unique send (not a trigger/repeated send) and/or the link alias is unique to this email, you may be able to use these dynamic tags instead.